# Type assertion in MyPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Some functions like [numpy.intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) return differents types (in this case an ndarray or a tuple of three ndarrays) but the compiler can only infer one of them, so if I like to make:

```
intersection: np.ndarray = np.intersect1d([1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 2])
```

It throws a type warning:

```
Expected type 'ndarray', got 'Tuple[ndarray, ndarray, ndarray]' instead
```

I could avoid this kind of problems in other languages like Typescript where I could use the `as` keyword to [assert the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (without impact in runtime). I've read the documentation and saw the [cast](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#when-you-re-puzzled-or-when-things-are-complicated) function, but I'd to know if there is any *inline* solution or something I'm missing.

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html - since the docs don't mention any alternative way to do type assertions, I would assume there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If you like make an answer and i'll mark as the accepted one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [MyPy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html#casts), there are two ways to do type assertions:

- As an inline expression, you can use the `typing.cast(..., ...)` function. The docs say this is "usually" done to cast from a supertype to a subtype, but doesn't say you can't use it in other cases.
- As a statement, you can use `assert isinstance(..., ...)`, but this will only work with concrete types like `int` or `list` which are represented at runtime, not more complex types like `List[int]` which can't be checked by `isinstance`.

Since the documentation doesn't mention any other ways to do type assertions, it seems like these are the only ways.