# Convert None to an exception

Tags: python

If I have a function that can return `None` (I can't change this function):

```py
def maybe() -> Optional[str]:
  ...
```

I want to use it in an expression e.g. like this:

```py
x = "Hello " + maybe() + " world"
```

This doesn't type check of course, but I want to have it throw an exception if `maybe()` returns `None`. (And I want it to work in the general case and pass type checking; I don't just want to rely on `+` throwing an exception.)

Obviously I can write a function to do this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def throw_if_none(x: Optional[T]) -> T:
  if x is None:
    raise Exception(...)
  return x
```

And then I can do this:

```py
x = "Hello " + throw_if_none(maybe()) + " world"
```

But **is there a built-in way to do this** without me having to write that function?

To be clear, I expect to have to modify the `x =`  line. I want to avoid having to define `maybe()`. I'm pretty sure there's no solution but I thought I should check in case I missed something.

Comment: The `TypeError` when you try to `+` a `None` value *is* the built-in way to do this; is there a specific reason that's not what you want? If you do need to raise a specific type of exception and/or with a specific exception message, then your custom function seems to be the only way to specify that. If the only problem with a straight `+` is the type-checking, then you could just use a [type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829680/type-assertion-in-mypy) to say the result is a `str`.

Comment: No `+` isn't the right way because I might not even have a `+`. That was just an example. A type assertion also isn't right because type assertions are intended to provide extra *correct* information to the type system that it can't figure out itself. Just saying "this can't be `None`" would be a lie.

Comment: OK, well, there is no built-in way to write an expression which raises if the value is `None` but results in the original value otherwise, so your custom function seems to be the only sensible way to do what you want. The only general mechanism I can think of that raises only on `None` would be attribute access, so you could write something like  `maybe(...).some_attr` to raise the exception, but then you don't get the original value (unless the objects in question must have some attribute which references themselves), and it still doesn't type-check.