# Mypy Assertions on the Types of Types

Tags: python, mypy

In Python, we can assign a type to an variable in this way and pass mypy's typecheck:

```
from typing import Type, Union


class Foo:
    pass


MyType: Type[Foo] = Foo
```

Similarly, we can also use `Union` for typing

```
from typing import Type, Union


class Foo:
    pass


class Bar:
    pass


def func(is_bar: bool) -> Union[Type[Foo], Type[Bar]]:
    if is_bar:
        return Bar
    else:
        return Foo
```

Knowing the value of `is_bar`, it would be totally reasonable to use assertions after calling `func` for type narrowing.

However, assertions do not seem to work at all for MyType as mypy is giving an error for the following code example:

```
MyType = func(True)

assert MyType is Bar  
# `assert MyType is Type[Bar]` gives the same result

Test: Bar = MyType  # Incompatible types in assignment (expression
                    # has type "Union[Type[Foo], Type[Bar]]",
                    # variable has type "Bar")
```

`cast` and `isinstance` do not work either.

```
MyType = func(True)
cast(Type[Bar], MyType)
Test: Bar = MyType  # MyType is considered `Type[Bar] | Type[Foo]`
```

```
MyType = func(True)
assert isintance(MyType, Type[Bar])
Test: Bar = MyType  # MyType is considered `Type[Bar] | Type[Foo]`
```

My questions is: ***how to do type narrowing for the types of types?*** Or is it a limitation of mypy? If that's so, what would be the workaround?

Related:

- [[1] stackoverflow - type-assertion-in-mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829680/type-assertion-in-mypy)
- [[2] Mypy doc - casts](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html)
- [[3] Mypy doc - kinds of types (the type of class objects)](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects)

Comment: MyPy is a static type checker. In your code the return type is determined during runtime. Prior to actually executing the code `func` may return either of those two classes and that is what MyPy is checking for.

Comment: @pavel Awaring that one of these two classes will be returned, and presuming that I'm with assurance that `Bar` will be given in runtime, how do I use assertions to **tell** mypy that `MyType` will be `Bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cast` helper *returns* its constrained argument, it does not actually *change* its argument to be constrained.

`cast` to the desired `Type[...]` and assign or use the result:

```py
Test = cast(Type[Bar], MyType)
reveal_type(Test)  # note: Revealed type is "Type[so_testbed.Bar]"
```

Comment: By the way, is there any reason why mypy doesn't support type inference for types with assertions?

Comment: @PIG208 Directly, the reason is that MyPy basically only understands ``isinstance`` conditionals; constructs like ``... is None`` are special cases. Indirectly, MyPy models types/metaclasses only skin-deep; ``Type[...]`` is a rather shallow special case itself. The somewhat meta-answer is that [first-class types are tricky for verification](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html), so MyPy draws the line of correctness versus completeness early where the effort is still acceptable and many people need it.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, that avoids having to use `typing.cast` or `isinstance`, is to use `typing.overload`, which allows you to register multiple signatures of a single function. All functions decorated with `@typing.overload` are ignored at runtime in favour of the "concrete" implementation, so the body of these functions can just be a literal ellipsis. By combining `typing.overload` with `typing.Literal`, we can register one signature of the function if the value `True` is passed in, and another if the value `False` is passed in:

```
from typing import Type, Union, overload, Literal


class Foo:
    pass


class Bar:
    pass


@overload
def func(is_bar: Literal[True]) -> Type[Bar]: ...


@overload
def func(is_bar: Literal[False]) -> Type[Foo]: ...


def func(is_bar: bool) -> Union[Type[Foo], Type[Bar]]:
    if is_bar:
        return Bar
    else:
        return Foo
        

test: Type[Bar] = func(True)
test2: Type[Foo] = func(False)
test3: Bar = func(True)()
test4: Foo = func(False)()
```

It type-checks fine.

Comment: Yes, this is also a valid workaround. I have thought about it, but the problem is that you will always need to define the functions when doing type narrowing.

Comment: If you're saying it's a shame that mypy can't do more complex code flow analysis, I'll agree with you there! But worth remembering it's still a pretty new tool, and pretty impressive for what it is.